# How to avoid maximum storage limit of cosmosdb for Scalar DL's asset records?

Tags: scalardl

I plan to store asset records in Scalar DL on Azure CosmosDB.

CosmosDB limits maximum storage size across all items per (logical) partition to 20GB.
Scalar DL's asset is partition key on Azure CosmosDB. So, the same asset is stored in same partition. I think there is a limitation of asset size on Azure CosmosDB.

Can we avoid this limitation?
Does Scalar DL have a feature to chain to another asset?

See also: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/concepts-limits

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The short answer is No.

First, any database systems usually have such limitations.
For example, DynamoDB partition has also 10 GB limitation.
Cassandra partition can have up to 2 billion cells but it is recommended to be smaller than 100 MB from performance perspective. (see https://www.instaclustr.com/cassandra-data-partitioning/)

So, it's always a good practice to model your asset properly not to grow too much.

If you know what you are doing and there are no other solutions except for having a large asset (partition), please split your asset into multiple assets. (e.g., if there is an asset that has an ID named Asset-A, create Asset-A-1, Asset-A-2, ..., Asset-A-M)
In such a case, an application has to also manage how they are split.

Comment: I'd like to use Scalar DL for evidence of documents.  Sometimes, number of documents is increasing... For example, expense reports, invoice, IP documents, etc. I will be considering to divide document group. ex) Ficical Year ( FY21 => Asset-FY21, FY22 => Asset-FY22), Document Number ( 1,000 => Asset-A-1, 2,000 => Asset-A-2, ...).